# How to execute an inner-join query on Firestore NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I have these two collections stored on Firestore.

[image: users]

[image: anuncios]

As you can see, the 'uid' field on users and 'createdBy' field on 'anuncios' have the same string data since the idea of the app is that each 'anuncio' created has the info of its creator. Then, I want to display on my app the name of that creator on each one [as this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ka6ml.png).
The problem that I'm facing is that I don't know how to match exactly the info I have on the users collection with the info I have on the anuncios collection. I have to display the 'displayName' from users but to do that I have to match that info comparying the 'uid' I have on users too with the 'createdBy' I have on anuncios. With SQL I would to that simply doing a join query but since NO-SQL databases can't perform that I'm a bit lost on how to achieve this. By the way, this is how I'm currently getting the anuncios data and displaying it on my frontend.

```
const [anuncios, setAnuncios] = useState([])
const [creadorAnuncio, setCreadorAnuncio] = useState([])
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)

const db = getFirestore(app);

useEffect(() => {

    const itemsRef = query(collection(db, 'anuncios'))
    getDocs(itemsRef)
        .then(res => {
            setAnuncios(res.docs.map((item) => ({ anuncioID: item.id, ...item.data() })
            ))
            setCreadorAnuncio(res.docs.map((item) => (item.data().createdBy)))
        })
        .finally(() => setLoading(false))

}, [])

anuncios.map((anuncio, i) => {
    console.log(creadorAnuncio)
    let q = query(collection(db, "users"), where("uid", "==", creadorAnuncio[i]));
    getDocs(q).then(res => {
        let x = res.docs.map((item) => (item.data().name))
        console.log(x)
    })
})

return(<div>{anuncios.map((anuncio, i) => (
                        <Link href='/' key={anuncio.id}>}</Link></div>)
```

Thanks

Update: this is what I get using the provided solution from @Dharmaraj

```
useEffect(() => {

    const getAnuncios = async () => {
        // Fetch Anuncios
        const itemsRef = query(collection(db, 'anuncios'))
        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(itemsRef)
        // Array of creator UIDs
        const creatorUids = [...new Set(querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data().createdBy))]
        //console.log(creatorUids)
        const creatorDocs = await Promise.all(creatorUids.map(uid => getDoc(doc(db, 'users', uid))))
        //console.log(creatorDocs)
        // Store creators data in a Map
        const creators = creatorDocs.reduce((acc, doc) => ({ ...acc, [doc.id]: doc.data() }), {})
        //console.log(creators)
        // Update state after creators data is fetched
        setAnuncios(querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })))
        setCreators(creators)
        console.log(creators)

        anuncios.map(anuncio => (
            console.log(anuncio),
            console.log(creators[anuncio.createdBy]?.name)
        ))
    }

    getAnuncios()
}, [])
```

[image: I get each anuncio correctly but it's not pairing the name with the uid]

Comment: Mimicking SQL joins in a NoSQL database can be considered as an anti-pattern. As explained in this ["famous" article](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/), NoSQL data modeling is typically driven by application-specific access patterns, i.e. the types of queries to be supported. Concretely, in your case, it means that in each `anuncio` doc you would duplicate the data of its author. This is called **denormalization** (which is indeed against SQL data-modelling best practices...) .../

Comment: .../ (cont.) One side effect of this approach is that you need to keep the data in sync (i.e. the ones in the user document and the ones in the `anuncio` documents). This synchronization could be done with a Cloud Function triggered if the `user` doc is modified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code can fetch same document multiple times if a single creator has created multiple *Anuncios*. You can first map an array of unique creators UIDs, query them and store in an object as shown below:

```
const [anuncios, setAnuncios] = useState([])
const [creators, setCreators] = useState({})

useEffect(() => {
  const getAnuncios = async () => {
    // Fetch Anuncios
    const itemsRef = query(collection(db, 'anuncios'))
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(itemsRef)
    // Array of creator UIDs
    const creatorUids = [...new Set(querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data().createdBy))]
    const creatorDocs = await Promise.all(creatorUids.map(uid => getDoc(doc(db, 'users', uid))))

    // Store creators data in a Map
    const creatorsData = creatorDocs.reduce((acc, doc) => ({ ...acc, [doc.id]: doc.data() }), {})

    console.log(creatorsData)

    // Update state after creators data is fetched
    setAnuncios(querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })))
    setCreators(creators)
  }

  getAnuncios()
}, [])

return (
  <div className="App">
    <h1>Anuncios</h1>
    <div>
      {anuncios.map(anuncio => (
        <div className="anuncio" key={anuncio.id}>
          <h2>{anuncio.currency} {anuncio.amount}</h2>
          <p>Created by: {creators[anuncio.createdBy]?.name}</p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  </div>
)
```

Comment: I've been trying this but 'const creators' returns me an array with undefined values, so I'm not getting the data at all :(

Comment: Where are you trying to log that? Can you share updated code? @LucaLago

Comment: Just updated it

Comment: @LucaLago can you try the updated answer? I renamed the const so its not same as in useState. Does that still log undefined?

Comment: Yes, it stills log undefined, it returns the same as I've shown on the image above, I don't know why it's not getting the paired values :@

Comment: @LucaLago that should not happen, can you please create a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) for your exact code and share the link so I can check what's wrong?

Comment: Sure, will do it in a few, thanks

Comment: I'm not very used to CodeSandbox, would you mind if I share with you the link to the github project? Sorry for the inconvenience btw https://github.com/lkl03/LibreCripto/tree/v2.0

Comment: @LucaLago you only have 2 document in your users collections with IDs - `eYCe6bw6UOn0n0OzAvQn` and `7VnMrwAUOW3sGLioRgQa`. But the `createdBy` field in `Anuncios` documents have different values and those values DO NOT exists in users collection. Can you either change `createdBy` values in the `Anuncios` collection or create those documents in users col?

Comment: So the code indeed is working as intended. If updating the values works out, you can accept and upvote the answer so others will know it's resolved :)

Comment: Now it worked, the problem is that I had the docs on the users collection with a random name, now each one has the name of the user uid and it's working fine, really thank you, you have been very kind with your help!